# Send data to PDF with Delphi

Tags: delphi, automation, pdf-generation, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

Is there a way I can send data to my PDF file, (fill in the fields/blanks), either manually or by a third party component, the PDF files have certain fields that can be modified by user, entering numbers.. checkboxes etc etc

how can I achieve this goal, an if it will require some third party component, which is the best, and what are the prices?

our Development IDE is delphi 2010 / Delphi 2011 XE

thanks :)

Comment: What is "send data to PDF"? Do you want to generate the PDF or fill the form(s) of existing PDF document? Please edit your question and specify the details.

Comment: I agree with Eugene - the question is very vague and needs clarification.

Comment: oh I am sorry, yes ofcourse I mean filling out forms in a PDF file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want your application to create some PDF content from User Interface field.

You can do this easily from code, using a report generator from code, then a [PDF engine](http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/Synopse-PDF-engine).

We propose an [Open Source solution just for doing this](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/30/Making-report-from-code), from Delphi 6 up to XE.

Here is a [code extract from one demo](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=41), which create a reports, using some User Interface fields as source (e.g. edt1.Text or mmo1.Text):

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  (...)
    with TGDIPages.Create(self) do
    try
      // the name of the report is taken from main Window's caption
      Caption := self.Caption;
      // now we add some content to the report
      BeginDoc;
      (...)
      // main content (automaticaly split on next pages)
      NewHalfLine;
      TextAlign := taJustified;
      s := 'This is some big text which must be justified on multiple lines. ';
      DrawText(s+s+s+s);
      NewLine;
      TextAlign := taLeft;
      DrawTitle(edt1.Text,true);
      for i := 1 to 10 do
        DrawText('This is some text '+IntToStr(i));
      NewLine;
      DrawBMP(Bmp,maxInt,50,'Some bitmap in the report');
      AddBookMark('bookmarkname');
      WordWrapLeftCols := true;
      AddColumns([10,20,50]);
      AddColumnHeaders(['#','Two','Three'],true,true);
      for i := 1 to 100 do
        DrawTextAcrossCols([IntToStr(i),'Column '+IntToStr(i),'Some text here. '+s]);
      NewLine;
      DrawBMP(Bmp,maxInt,50,'Some bitmap in the report (twice)');
      DrawTitle('This is your text',false,0,'','bookmarkname');
      DrawText(mmo1.Text);
      EndDoc;
      // set optional PDF export options
      // ExportPDFForceJPEGCompression := 80;
      // ExportPDFEmbeddedTTF := true;
      // ExportPDFUseUniscribe := true;
      // ExportPDFA1 := true;
      // show a preview form, and allow basic actions via the right click menu
      // ShowPreviewForm;
      // export as PDF
      ExportPDF('test.pdf',false);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

There are other solutions around, but this one is Open Source, and you can even draw whatever you want to the report (using a "standard" TCanvas property - you can even directly any graphical component using the PaintTo method), not only dedicated report generated methods like DrawTitle() or DrawText().

*EDIT:*

If your question was about creating PDF files with forms, this library won't work.

You should use some closed-source libraries like [VeryPdf](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfform/index.html) or [QuickPdf](http://help.quickpdflibrary.com/questions/794/formfields-fill-in-problems-with-an-existing-pdf-file). [Google is your friend](http://www.google.at/search?q=PDF+fill-in+delphi).

Comment: This one can be usefull in my other projects where I might need a free PDF generator, however I am looking for a way to modify existing PDF files, i.e. Filling out the blanks (fields) like in a locked word document you can have certain fields which can be modified, and the rest of the file remains read only... you send your strings to these blanks

Comment: @Plastkort So you'll need a PDF viewer. You can either embed Acrobat Reader as ActiveX. Either use a pure Delphi solution like http://www.wpcubed.com/products/pdfviewer/index.htm but there is no open source solution, as far as I know. :(